# How to append suffix to file names in write.csv() in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, append

I have many data frames. I write them to csv, but I would not like to manually enter to each file the ending '_100' only to be able to specify it once and that each file would write with this ending

```
    write.csv(results_SVM, file = "results_SVM.csv")
    write.csv(results_ANN, file = "results_ANN.csv")
    write.csv(results_RBF, file = "results_ANN.csv")
```

Get the same suffix for each file:

```
write.csv(results_SVM, file = "results_SVM_100.csv")
write.csv(results_ANN, file = "results_ANN_100.csv")
write.csv(results_RBF, file = "results_ANN_100.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` in the filename:

```
#suf <- "" #nothing
suf <- "_100" #with _100

write.csv(results_SVM, file = paste0("results_SVM",suf,".csv"))
write.csv(results_ANN, file = paste0("results_ANN",suf,".csv"))
write.csv(results_RBF, file = paste0("results_ANN",suf,".csv"))
```

Comment: It would be more helpful, if he store all result as `list` and then use combination of  `map` and `paste` to write all data at once.